# Expand and collapse nested grid with a parent row click in telerik wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a nested grid and I want to expand it and collapse it with a parent row click. It expands with parent row click per default but if I want to collapse it I have to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. I want to be able to collapse it again on the parent row click without holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button. How is that possible?

I'm working with C# with Telerik WPF.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand.

In the method of click in the parent, add "nameOfChildren".Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;